# Stopping all subsequent calls to subscribe in reactive extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am replacing some of my previously  written code with reactive extensions.

Previously I was using File.ReadAllLines(FileName) and then loop through all the lines of files and in this loop at some point, I break from the loop and perform some operation on the processed records(which now I want to do in the OnCompleted action of Subscribe method).

Now I am trying to use this

```
var observableSequence = File.ReadAllLines(FileName).ToObservable();
observableSequence.Subscribe(u=>
{
//doing some thing but at some point I  need to stop receving further calls and go for the OnCompleted action.
});
```

I understand there is a cheap hack of If condition which wont satisfied after that condition but still I don't want to waste my CPU cycles over processing unnecessary events.

The only way I know to stop  doing this is by Disposing the subscription but at this point while I am in between subscribing this wont be possible.

So is there any way I could ignore all the events at some point and jump straight to OnCompleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want some sort of manual way to stop the observable, you could try this:

```
var signal = new Subject<Unit>();
var observableSequence =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(FileName)
        .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
        .TakeUntil(signal);
var count = 0;
observableSequence.Subscribe(u=>
{
    if (++count == 100) 
    {
        signal.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }
}, () => Console.WriteLine(count));

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

It would be preferable to do it as part of the query though. Something like this:

```
var observableSequence =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(FileName)
        .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
        .TakeWhile((x, n) => n < 10);
var count = 0;
observableSequence.Subscribe(u => ++count, () => Console.WriteLine(count));

Console.WriteLine(count);
```